# Excel DateDif() or =NETWORKDAYS()

Tags: excel, function

I tried the functions listed in the subject, DateDif() and =NETWORKDAYs() with these parameters, =NETWORKDAYS(Today(), 5/31/2015). Now I keep getting an unusually large number for the context on my spreadsheet. I am not sure why.
Any ideas?

```
=DateDif(5/31/2015,Today(), "D")
```

I get:

```
42237.0
```

This obviously is not true. Since in the last few months there have not been nearly that many days.

Comment: 42237 is the number that represents today's date. 42237 days since January 1, 1900, the first real date supported in Excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slashes are interpreted as division signs so `5 ÷ 31 ÷ 2015` is almost 0, which means Jan 00, 1900. (I kid you not, there is such a date in Excel).

Use this:

```
=DateDif(DATE(2015,5,31),Today(), "D")
```

Which gives 82 days.

Comment: Thank you. that makes sense.